# installing TYPO3 in macOS Catalina localhost: Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException

Tags: macos, localhost, typo3, installation, macos-catalina

I am trying to use TYPO3 on a local web server. I have a Mac Catalina. But when I enter the URL: `localhost/blog` from the browser, I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Could not create directory "/Users/fjosenova/Sites/vblog8/typo3temp/var/log/"! in /Users/fjosenova/Sites/vblog8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php:2085 Stack trace: 
#0 /Users/fjosenova/Sites/vblog8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php(2053): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::createDirectoryPath('/Users/fjosenov...') 
#1 /Users/fjosenova/Sites/vblog8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Log/Writer/FileWriter.php(226): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::mkdir_deep('/Users/fjosenov...') 
#2 /Users/fjosenova/Sites/vblog8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Log/Writer/FileWriter.php(192): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\Writer\FileWriter->createLogFile() 
#3 /Users/fjosenova/Sites/vblog8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Log/Writer/FileWriter.php(122): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\Writer\FileWriter->openLogFile() 
#4 /Users/fjosenova/Sites/vblog8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Log/Writer/FileWriter.php(81): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\Writer\FileWriter->setLogFile('/Users/fjosenov...') 
#5 /Users/fjosenova/Sites/vb in /Users/fjosenova/Sites/vblog8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php on line 2085
```

I've googled but can't find anything to help me solve the problem. It seems to be about permissions. From the terminal application I have looked at the permissions I have and have changed them to 775.
Please, would you be so kind as to tell me how to solve it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt solve your problem but I'd def. recommend to use DDEV instead of trying to setup an custom local apache/nginx
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-contributionworkflow/master/en-us/Appendix/SettingUpTypo3Ddev.html

Answer (score 1):

be aware that apache normale runs with it's own user - which is another one than your user. so both users should have access to the files and folders where TYPO3 is running.

add your user to the usual group of the aapche user (probably www:www) and make sure all your files belong to that group and the group has enough rights to write.

```
chown -R fjosenova:www *


chmod -R g+w *
or:
find . -type d -exec chmod 2775 "{}" \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 "{}" \;
```